# Create a bootstrap 3 button with 3 horizontal dashes or lines

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I create a bootstrap 3 button with an icon having 3 horizontal lines/dashes as typical web button for settings. ?

I can not find such an ico/glyphicon so how can I do it maybe with css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

demo - http://www.bootply.com/92Ka6oLOVO

You can create your own icon

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.glyphicon-nav {
  width: 18px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.glyphicon-nav:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  top: 0px;
}
.glyphicon-nav:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: Red;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-nav" aria-hidden="true"></span> Setting
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the bootply here you get a plunker in return ;-) http://plnkr.co/edit/mTia01WbXeFORvRMmkRw?p=preview

Comment: Can you tell me please how to tweak the middle horizontal dash in the thickness? I can change the first and third dash but not the middle one...

Comment: Thanks that worked. Do you know of a boostrap only solution using the bootstrap grid layout where no pixel values are used to define the width/height of the 3 dashes that its behavior is responsive - without using media queries of course -

Comment: you can use [**font-Awesonem**](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) `fa fa-bars`

Comment: haha... Font awesome I already checked but have not seen the bars... searched for line/dash. Great remaining DRY!

Answer (score 0):

I copied the following code from http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-toggle {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    display: block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 1px;
}
```

Obviously I didn't test above. You will be able to find any missing pieces by studying the page I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the symbole in Bootstrap that apperars at a small Device for the menue?

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
```

So you have 3 "icon-bar" in the button.

if it was not what you mean, look at http://glyphicons.com/, there  you'll find some more icons.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50yFG.png)

```css
.navbar-toggler-icon {
   width:auto;
   height:auto;
}
.line { 
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-style: inset;
    border: 2px solid rgb(136, 133, 133);
    width: 35px;
  }
```

```html
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <hr class="line">
            <hr class="line">
            <hr class="line">
          </button>
```